# Succinct way to use GADTs for exhaustiveness-checking in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums, pattern-matching, gadt, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm looking for the same behavior as the following OCaml code, where the compiler understands the match is exhaustive because we've expressed that the two scrutinees must have the same type:

```ml
type circle
type rectangle

type _ figure =
    | Circle : int -> circle figure
    | Rectangle : int * int -> rectangle figure

let equal_figure : type a. a figure -> a figure -> bool = fun f1 f2 -> match (f1, f2) with
| Circle r1, Circle r2 -> Int.(r1 = r2)
| Rectangle (x1, y1), Rectangle (x2, y2) -> Int.(x1 = x2 && y1 = y2)
(* the compiler knows this match is exhaustive *)
```

I can port the example directly to Scala and the exhaustiveness-checker does the right thing:

```scala
sealed trait CircleMarker
sealed trait RectangleMarker

enum Fig[T]:
  case Circle(r: Int) extends Fig[CircleMarker]
  case Rectangle(x: Int, y: Int) extends Fig[RectangleMarker]

def equalFig[T](f1: Fig[T], f2: Fig[T]): Boolean = (f1, f2) match
  case (Fig.Circle(r1), Fig.Circle(r2))               => r1 == r2
  case (Fig.Rectangle(x1, y1), Fig.Rectangle(x2, y2)) => x1 == x2 && y1 == y2
  (* the compiler knows this match is exhaustive *)
```

> [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CD1pDgTWQXKiVqvTAcY6GA)

Is there a more succinct way to express this in Scala, without the phantom `CircleMarker` and `RectangleMarker` traits?

Comment: If you're not instantiating/extensing `CircleMarker`, `RectangleMarker` they can be abstract types rather than traits https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/6oE7Jpe3Sxm5XFAgyT9ECA/4 Also you can try F-bounds https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/6oE7Jpe3Sxm5XFAgyT9ECA If you're not hiding implementation types (cases types) this can be just a sealed-trait hierarchy https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/6oE7Jpe3Sxm5XFAgyT9ECA/2 Actually, `equals` is already defined for case classes https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/6oE7Jpe3Sxm5XFAgyT9ECA/3

Comment: The F-bounds example is perfect, if you submit it as an answer I can mark it accepted so it's discoverable.

Comment: Re `equals`: it's a toy example, but there's an interesting difference between your last implementation and the original: in the original `equalFig(Fig.Circle(1), Fig.Rectangle(1, 2))` is ill-typed, but in your last example it's well-typed.

Comment: *"but in your last example it's well-typed"* Sorry I don't understand. It seems to be still ill-typed https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/6oE7Jpe3Sxm5XFAgyT9ECA/10

Comment: *"The F-bounds example is perfect, if you submit it as an answer I can mark it accepted"* done

Comment: I see, scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/6oE7Jpe3Sxm5XFAgyT9ECA/10 is indeed ill-typed. I think scastie was funky on my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [F-bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)

```
enum Fig[T <: Fig[T]]:
  case Circle(r: Int) extends Fig[Circle]
  case Rectangle(x: Int, y: Int) extends Fig[Rectangle]

// sealed trait Fig[T <: Fig[T]]
// object Fig:
//   case class Circle(r: Int) extends Fig[Circle]
//   case class Rectangle(x: Int, y: Int) extends Fig[Rectangle]

def equalFig[T <: Fig[T]](f1: Fig[T], f2: Fig[T]): Boolean = (f1, f2) match
  case (Fig.Circle(r1), Fig.Circle(r2))               => r1 == r2
  case (Fig.Rectangle(x1, y1), Fig.Rectangle(x2, y2)) => x1 == x2 && y1 == y2

// def equalFig[T <: Fig[T]](f1: Fig[T], f2: Fig[T]): Boolean = f1 == f2

equalFig(Fig.Circle(1), Fig.Circle(1)) // true
equalFig(Fig.Circle(1), Fig.Circle(2)) // false
equalFig(Fig.Rectangle(1, 2), Fig.Rectangle(1, 2)) // true
equalFig(Fig.Rectangle(1, 2), Fig.Rectangle(1, 3)) // false
// equalFig(Fig.Circle(1), Fig.Rectangle(1, 2)) // doesn't compile
```